# Is it possible to set user password policy based on group membership in Linux?

Tags: linux, security, passwords, pam

I wanted to set a password restriction policy like `minlen`, `maxage`, `minage` etc…

I know the way to do it system wide but can it be done for a particular group of users.

I mean only users under group of `admin` should comply with these restriction and other users should comply these restrictions..

Answer (score 1):

You say that you know how to enforce a password policy system-wide, but I'll reiterate what to do for anyone who doesn't. You can use a PAM module, `pam_cracklib.so`, that checks to make sure a password meets certain criteria before allowing the password to be applied to an account. In Ubuntu, the package `libpam-cracklib` installs this module, and applies the following line to the top of `/etc/pam.d/common-password`, the file that deals with changing a user's password:

```
password    requisite           pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
```

Various options can be passed to `pam_cracklib.so`, and in this case a minimum length of 8 is specified with a requirement of 3 character changes from the old password. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib for a detailed list of every option available.

To limit one policy for a certain group of users, it is possible to utilise the `pam_succeed_if.so` module, that only succeeds if a user matches various criteria. For example, to enforce a password policy like the one above, but leaving users in the 'sudo' group exempt, use:

```
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup sudo
password    requisite           pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
```

This tells PAM to check if the user matches group 'sudo', then skip the next module if that succeeds. Otherwise, continue on with the next module, which enforces a password policy.

However, if using a PAM module with the option `use_authtok` like the default Ubuntu `pam_unix.so` configuration with pam_cracklib.so installed, this will not work quite right. Since `pam_unix.so` depends on a module previously to have set the current user password and desired password, should the `pam_succeed_if.so` module succeed then `passwd` will error out with `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error`. The way I got around it was to use a second `pam_unix.so` line:

```
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup sudo
password    requisite           pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

In this example, should the user be in group 'sudo', control skips 2 modules down to the final `pam_unix.so` line which does not include `use_authtok`. Should it fail however, control passes to `pam_cracklib.so`, then to the dependent `pam_unix.so`

Comment: Great Help sir , I worked ..

Comment: I have 1 more query , I want that whenever user run passwd command it should display some banner like minimum length required =8 etc..

Comment: For this you can use `pam_echo.so` a module that simply echoes out a message. For example, to echo out the contents of a file that details what a good password is, use `password optional pam_echo.so file=/usr/share/doc/good-password.txt`, putting that line before any others in common-password.

Comment: Also, if the answer above worked for you, please don't forget to mark it as accepted